# LaTeX Error: File `l3regex.sty' not found

Tags: errors

For TWMS Journal of Applied and Engineering Mathematics (TWMS J. of Apl. & Eng. Math.) Journal, I downloaded Latex template. If I run the file using Winedt 10.2, I am getting "LaTeX Error: File `l3regex.sty' not found" error. I Updated both MikTex and WinEdt. But still its showing same error.

Following Packages using in the template

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{coloring}
\usepackage{expl3}
```

Comment: a separate l3regex package no longer exists, the code has been merged into expl3. Which package is trying to load it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's `coloring`, which looks ... not my favourite

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `coloring` package: I'm not sure I'd use it. If you must, then you can trick LaTeX into thinking it's loaded

```latex
\expandafter\def\csname ver@l3regex.sty\endcsname{}
```

before loading `coloring`.